# Update Data in Firebase With VueJS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to update a value under a certain key without using the "naive" way of copy/pasting the key value. Because I want it to scale to any client.

I basically want to update on click the "edit" property to "true".

Here's my current tree structure:
[image]

My current method:

```
      var query= db.ref('Clients/AgenceEco/forms/step1/');
          query.update({
              edit: true
      })
```

The problem is that it actually adds an edit property under the "step1", like the following: 
[image]

I obviously don't want that but want to update the value under the random generated key of firebase.

How would you go about solving this issue? Thanks

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Vue specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
var updates = {};
updates['Clients/AgenceEco/forms/step1/edit'] = true;
db.ref().update(updates);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update

Edit: Regarding your comments you could do this (but I think there may be an easier way of doing it):

```
var ref = 'Clients/AgenceEco/forms/step1';
firebase.database().ref(ref).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    if (data) {
        data.edit = true;
        firebase.database().ref(ref).update(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Camden_kid...unforntunately this added a whole new tree with "Clients/AgenceEco/forms/step1/edit" under the unique id key -KyLgpQY1UShZELIgdOz

Comment: Any ideas on just targeting the "edit" property under that unique key? Thanks

Comment: @Tony If you have access to the key then it would be `updates['Clients/AgenceEco/forms/step1/key/edit'] = true;`, e.g. `updates['Clients/AgenceEco/forms/step1/LyLgpQY1UShZELIgd0z/edit'] = true;`

Comment: Thankss! In my case i don't have access to the key...would you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just do that on child, not step1 directly. With `child` method:

```
var query= db.ref('Clients/AgenceEco/forms/step1/')
query.child().update({
  edit: true
})
```

Comment: Hi @WaldemarIce, unfortunately I get: "Reference.child failed: Was called with 0 arguments." I see what you're saying, but i cannot target that specific unique key under step1. Any ideas?